# How can I browse remote git repositories (like I used to do with CVS)?

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, cvs

I just finished converting my CVS repository to git. With my CVS repo, I could connect with eclipse (via Import -> Projects from CVS -> Use an existing module), and view a list of all of my projects.

With git, I can't seem to do that. I have to manually type in the name of a project I want to check out, making it necessary for me to ssh into the remote machine just to run `ls ~/.git` to remember the name.

Is there a way to list all of my projects in Eclipse? Maybe with a plugin? I own the server, so if I need extra configuration on either end, that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible directly in EGit: it only allows to access a specific Git repo through its url, not to list all repos of a git server.

Browsing multiple repos is done separately, through for instance a gitweb interface, meaning a web browser. (gitweb is shipped with git, so you can activate it on your server).
See [**`gitweb`** man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitweb).

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid this was the case. I'll check out gitweb. I'm leaving the question open for now in hope for an alternative solution.